# How to count in a loop?

Tags: ruby, loops

I'm new to Ruby, how can I count elements in a loop?
In Java I would write it like this

```
int[] tablica = { 23,53,23,13 };
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) { // **only first two**
    sum += tablica[i];
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

**EDIT:** I want only first two

Comment: is this Ruby or C? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tablica.take(2).reduce(:+)
```

But seriously? What's wrong with just

```
tablica[0] + tablica[1]
```

Hey, it even works in Ruby *and* Java … and C, C++, Objective-C, Objective-C++, D, C#, ECMAScript, PHP, Python. *Without* changes.

Comment: it wont work if I dont how many elements I want and  passed to function as parameter(without huge if). nice trick.

Answer (score 5):

You can sum all the elements in an array like this:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
arr.inject(:+)
# any operator can be here, it will be
# interpolated between the elements (if you use - for example
# you will get 1-2-3-4-5-6)
```

Or, if you want to iterate over the elements:

```
arr.each do |element|
    do_something_with(element)
```

Or, if you need the index too:

```
arr.each_with_index do |element, index|
    puts "#{index}: #{element}"
```

Comment: caveat: on empty arrays you usually want to return 0, that's why some solutions use inject(0, ...). Otherwise you get nil.

Comment: @Zabba: I love the fact it looks like an emoticon.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm, didn't notice that :p

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a sum, here is a simple way:

```
tablica = [ 23,53,23,13 ]
puts tablica.inject(0){|sum,current_number| sum+current_number}
```

For first two elements (or whatever contiguous range) you can use a range:

```
tablica = [ 23,53,23,13 ]
puts tablica[0..1].inject(0){|sum,current_number| sum+current_number}
```

What this does:

1. The block (the statement within `{...}`) is called internally by `inject`, once for each element in the array.
2. At the first iteration, `sum` has the initial value `0` (that we passed to `inject`)
   And `current_number` contains the 0th element in the array.
3. We add the two values (0 and 23) and this value gets assigned to `sum` when the block returns.
4. Then on the next iteration, we get `sum` variable as 23 and `current_number` as 53. And the process repeats.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, but if you want the current object *and* a counter use the each_with_index method

```
some_collection.each_with_index do |o, i|
  # 'o' is your object, 'i' is your index
end
```

EDIT: Oops, read that too quickly.  You can do this

```
sum = 0
some_collection.each { |i| sum += i }
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Enumerable#inject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001494):

```
tablica = [23, 53, 23, 13]
tablica.inject(0, :+) # 112
```